# Copy multiple columns from different tables and pasting them alternated

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

This [example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xkoyq45IrOx1ig_xwzLQ0u9khu3vI_xzqsSq3_CquPs/edit?usp=sharing) explains far better my question; Is it possible to copy first one column fra one sheet/table and concatenated two other columns AND then repeat that 4 times (mon-fri)?

Comment: So you want to show the sports/activities only if there is a name in the names tab?

Comment: Exactly. Brilliant!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In sheet 'Ark9' I entered in A1

```
=ArrayFormula(trim({
fruit!A2:A7\if(names!A2:A7<>""; week!A2:A7&" ("&names!A2:A7&")";)\
fruit!B2:B7\if(names!B2:B7<>""; week!B2:B7&" ("&names!B2:B7&")";)\
fruit!C2:C7\if(names!C2:C7<>""; week!C2:C7&" ("&names!C2:C7&")";)\
fruit!D2:D7\if(names!D2:D7<>""; week!D2:D7&" ("&names!D2:D7&")";)\
fruit!E2:E7\if(names!E2:E7<>""; week!E2:E7&" ("&names!E2:E7&")";)
}))
```

See if that works for you?